# Can't find setVisible() in a Netbeans-created jFrame form

Tags: netbeans, jframe, visibility

I've got a jFrame Form with an action handler that instantiates a new form and switches over to it using setVisible(true). That much works.

When I try to setVisible(false) on the current form, however, I get an error:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setVisible(boolean)
  location: class foo.bar
----
```

My action handler looks like this:

```
public void Login() {
    //#TODO Log in code

    setVisible(false); // <-- Error here
    mainPage.mainScreen ms = new mainPage.mainScreen();
    ms.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to hide the "main" view, so to speak, and netbeans won't allow this. I can instantiate a different view, show it, and it can show and hide itself all day long.